# Where to find directory of content created in drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-8

I created a content type from admin panel and made a view and block of that content. Added Block to the content region. Where can i find the file in which these code are made??

Comment: you are looking for the template of your view ?

Comment: template of view which i created from admin panel.